# while installing moodle error occurs HTTP Error 403.14

Tags: iis, moodle

while installing moodle error occurs HTTP Error 403.14

i have done too much but still showing like this error.

now pls suggest wht to do?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

1) Set IIS Manager-> Application pools -> Your sites pool -> Advanced settings -> Identity -> NETWORK SERVICE

also set .Net framework version to v4.0

2) Add full rights for your sites folder for “NETWORK SERVICE”, ”IUSR” and ”IIS_IUSRS” users

if its not helps run this command:

for 32bit (x86)

%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe -ir

for 64bit (x64)

%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe -ir

you can find more information about comands here:
https://devstuffs.wordpress.com/2012/02/29/how-to-fix-http-error-403-14-forbidden-the-web-server-is-configured-to-not-list-the-contents-of-this-directory/